# newChooseAccountIntent force open dialog in android 6.0

Tags: java, android, accountpicker

I use this function for account chose and pick get user's email.

```
    private void pickUserAccount() {

        String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"}; 

        try { // request account

            Intent intent = AccountPicker
                    .newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);

            startActivityForResult(intent, AuthProcess.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);

/*
        Error control

*/

        } catch (CriticalException e) {

            throw e;

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) { // problems with memory    

            throw e;

        } catch (Throwable e) { // Other exceptions

            final String message = "Error during google account picker dialog: " + e;

            throw new CriticalException(logcat, message);

        } 

    } // End: pickUserAccount
```

In android 6.0 this code open dialog for chose account in spite of only one google account present at the device. In android 4.4.2 it work nice. What's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Anything useful in the Logcat?

Comment: utility library provided html debug output, device file logging, text operations etc

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Can you update your question with the Logcat?

Comment: This code open dialog:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9H-yfu0v-2AX2NNdDRvMzc4Q2s/view

The only one google account present at the device. In android 4.4.2 I recive user e-mail at once (only one google account mean than only one e-mail can be received - no need to open account choose dialog)